# How to change default of max open files per process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I changed the max open files to 20000. However I'm still running into limits and I found that there is a per process limit. I would like to know how to change this the default per process limit too?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-137-139:~$ cat /proc/1237/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             31538                31538                processes 
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       31538                31538                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us        

ubuntu@ip-172-16-137-139:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31538
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 20000               <- changed this
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31538
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: this limit is per user, not per process

Comment: So how do I change the per process limit from 1024?

Comment: /etc/security/limits.conf and man limits.conf for more information.

Comment: I already set the open files there to 20000

    # <domain> <type> <item>  <value>
        *       soft  nofile  20000
        *       hard  nofile  20000

Comment: @stevo999999, logout and login again. then restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

[The getrlimit and setrlimit calls](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html) control most per-process resource allocation limits. `RLIMIT_NOFILE` controls the maximum number of file descriptors. You will need appropriate permissions to call it.

Comment: its not what I'm trying to set because I ran the `Process.getrlimit(:NOFILE)` and got back
=> [20000, 20000]